# Programatically dynamic navigation with hooks in next.js

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, material-table

I have an application based on next.js framework in which I use material-table component to handle tables in the project. This library has a props called onRowClick, which in turn takes a function attached to the native onClick props of each row in the column. What I'm trying to get at this point is a dynamic link that will take the user to the appropriate page on the click.

Dynamic links are still a little unclear to me in next.js, but what I have tried so far:

```
//The class organizin paths in the application (simplified)
export default class Routes {
    public static PLAYERS = '/players';
    public static PLAYER = (id: number) => `${Routes.PLAYERS}/${id}`;
    public static PLAYER_SCHEME = `${Routes.PLAYERS}/[id]`;}

….

const router = useRouter();
//I am providing here a dynamic path scheme and as the second dynamic path parameter to be filled for each player separately
const redirect = async (id: number) => router.push(Routes.PLAYER_SCHEME, Routes.PLAYER(id));

…

//Passing function to the table
onRowClick={async (_, row) => (row?.id ? redirect(row.id) : undefined)}
```

Everything works potentially well. however, my `Players` component in Pages folder is executing request for api data based on id param from url. Unfortunately pushing route to the router this way, twice renders `pages/Players/[id]` component, which first in params id gets a null and next correct id.

**TL;DR** 
What is the correct way to create dynamic links in next.js when I can't use the Link component, because it will disrupt the semantics of app html structure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Router from Next.js

```
import Router from 'next/router'

cosnt redirect = (url) => {
    Router.push(url)
}
```

For example:

```
Router.push('/login');
Router.push('/products/' + id);
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that we lose the state of our parent components, because in my experience it works like a regular js redirect function.

Comment: Yes, a redirect (or .push) refreshes the whole page, and that is the expected behaviour. If you want to update only part of the page you need a different approach.